# Output of a command in a bash script is different from normal command

Tags: bash

i am using opensuse as a virtual machine on my laptop.
this question is about code that i need to do for my homework.

I need to make a script with a variable that shows the amount of entries in a directory.

when i write the exact command in a bash script the output is diffrent from when i run it directly from the CLI

```
#! /bin/bash

clear

ENTRIES=$(ls /tmp | wc -l)

echo "the amount of entries is" "$ENTRIES"
```

When i run this script the output will be 53

but when i type the command "ls /tmp | wc -l" in the terminal/CLI i get 61

does anyone know how to solve/explain this?

I got confused and went to look online for answers but I could not find any that's why I am asking this question

thanks for the effort

Sorry for any spelling mistakes. I‘m from the Netherlands.

Comment: Are the results consistent? Anything could be creating files in `/tmp`; the difference could simply be due to *when* you ran the command versus any differences between a script and the interactive prompt.

Comment: I changed the folder to "/home/jan" in the script and in the normal command. the output of the script is 2 but the output of the normal command is 13

Comment: Well, what are the actual contents of the directory? Also, do you have any aliases like `alias ls='ls -a'`? Aliases won't be set or expanded for your script.

Comment: (Comparing the output of `ls /home/jan` itself in both settings should help clear this up as well. If you don't understand the counts, look at what's actually being counted.)

Comment: i don't have any aliases set the script you see above is the full script (its work in progress). i first want this to be sorted out.

Comment: when i use "ls /home/jan" i get 2 directory's called "bin" and "Public_html" and when i use ls /home/jan from the cli i get 13 directory's including the 2 said erlier

Comment: maybe its something with permissions?

Comment: Try `entries=$(echo *); echo ${#entries}`

Comment: Why don't you have a look at which files exist in one but not the other? That would give helpful clues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command substitution might be implemented in a way which creates a temporary file.

More likely, the number of files in `/tmp` naturally varies over time, and you postulate a causation where there just happened to be a correlation.

A better way to implement this avoids [parsing `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) using either an array

```
#!/bin/bash
tmpfiles=(/tmp/*)
echo "$(#tmpfiles[@]} files in /tmp"
```

or just enumerating the files, which is portable to POSIX `sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -- /tmp/*
echo "$# files in /tmp"
```

Printing out the array or list of arguments should reveal which files exactly were present.

As an aside, don't use upper case for your private variables; uppercase variable names are reserved for system variables.